# How do I validate radiobuttons using a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a computing assignment to do.

I've done most I'm just stuck on this task:

```
"Add a set of radio buttons to the form to accept a level of entry such as
 GCSE, AS or A2. Write a function that displays the level of entry to the user
 in an alert box so that the level can be confirmed or rejected."
```

I have done the Radio Buttons I just don't know how to do the second part with the Alertbox and function.

So far my code looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Exam entry</title>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function validateForm() {
                var result = true;
                var msg="";

                if (document.ExamEntry.name.value == "") {
                    msg += "You must enter your name \n";
                    document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
                    document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
                    result = false;
                }
                if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value == "") {
                    msg += "You must enter the subject \n";
                    document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
                    document.getElementById('subject').style.color = "red";
                    result = false;
                }
                if (document.ExamEntry.examno.value == "") {
                    msg += "You must enter your Examination Number \n";
                    document.ExamEntry.examno.focus();
                    document.getElementById('examinationno').style.color = "red";
                    result = false;
                }

                if (msg=="") {
                    return result;
                }

                {
                    alert(msg)
                    return result;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head> 

    <! Main HTML content begins >

    <body>
        <h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
        <form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
            <table width="50%" border="0">
                <tr></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="name">Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="subject">Subject</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="subject" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="examinationno">Examination Number</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="examno" maxlength="4" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <td><input type="radio" name="Level" value="GCSE">GCSE</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="Level" value="AS">AS</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="Level" value="A2">A2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onClick="return validateForm();" /></td>
                    <td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is add the value of the radio button to the message like this:

```
msg += "Level of Entry: "+document.ExamEntry.Level.value;
```

[**Here is a fiddle demo you can try**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qd8sk/1/)

**EDIT #1:** Though it has been said to use an *alert* box, that wouldn't actually allow the user to confirm or reject, for that, you could use *confirm* instead:

```
if (confirm("Click OK to confirm your Level of Entry or Cancel if you would like to correct it"))
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

In my example, I added it only in case the rest of the form validation was successful: [**http://jsfiddle.net/Qd8sk/2/**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qd8sk/2/)

**EDIT #2:** Following our conversation, I updated the jsfiddle you created. It is much more simple than what you provided.

Here is yours: http://jsfiddle.net/Kjxmn/

Here is mine: http://jsfiddle.net/Kjxmn/2/

Several things I changed:

-1. Added `return` in front of the function name in `onchange` - looks like otherwise it would still submit even on `return false`.

-2. Corrected the form name that you called `radioform` this time, not `Exam Entry`.

-3. Got rid of the slightly cumbersome check of the selected value using `if (document.radioform.level.value == '')` instead.

-4. Added the *confirm* check.

**EDIT #3:** Looks like firefox doesn't like the usage of `document.ExamEntry.Level.value` for radio buttons, so instead I created a quick workaround that would loop through the elements of `document.ExamEntry.Level` and find the one that is 'selected' ('checked' actually - even though it's a radio button, the js code is still called 'checked').

Have a look at the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qd8sk/3/

Comment: What about **the level can be confirmed or rejected.** ?

Comment: they said it has to be an alert box, not a confirm, you could still accept or decline by clicking ok, going back and making the right selection.

Comment: If i click OK, the form will be submitted immediately. Yep, if the rejection or confirmation should be done by user - it's correct. Awful, but correct :)

Comment: k, I added that option, it totally make sense @MikeGrabowski, thanks!

Comment: Only thing is, it also wants me to display the level of entry to the user.@webeno

Comment: @webeno    I had made another program, just for the radio buttons which worked.  It did what i needed only thing was i don't know how to get it into this program.

Comment: I added it to the 2nd version of my fiddle (see last line of my answer), have you checked that one?

Comment: Yeah but every time i try that it keeps coming up as 'undefined'?

Comment: copy your code into fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) and test it there, open developer tools (inspect element) and check the output on the console... if it's still not working, save it and paste the url here so I can have a look...

Comment: i didn't mean an empty collab session... get familiar with jsfiddle (do your homework) setup the code there, then share it

Comment: Never used jsfiddle until now sorry

Comment: @webeno Do you know how i could get that program into the exam entry one?

Comment: And Every time i use your first jsfiddle it come up with the alertbox but says "Level of Entry: undefined"

Comment: dude, if you're using a different code, why are you not posting that on jsfiddle? How do you expect me to help...?

Comment: Im using the exam entry one, but i used that just to workout how to get the alert box to come up @webeno

Comment: I have been using your first jsfiddle but it keeps saying undefined

Comment: why would you use my first fiddle if I have posted 2 more in my edited answer, all of them working perfectly??? IF you tell me WHAT you want, or AT LEAST post the FULL freakin' code into ONE jsfiddle, THEN I can help...

Comment: so what's wrong with [http://jsfiddle.net/Qd8sk/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/Qd8sk/2/) for example?

Comment: All i really want to do is this task on my code "Add a set of radio buttons to the form to accept a level of entry such as
 GCSE, AS or A2. Write a function that displays the level of entry to the user
 in an alert box so that the level can be confirmed or rejected"

Comment: dude, can you not read below the first lines of my answer...? i also pasted a second fiddle, in fact i pasted it again a few comments back, but let me do it a 3rd time, maybe this time you'll get it: [http://jsfiddle.net/Qd8sk/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/Qd8sk/2/) - now tell me EXACTLY what you don't like about this one...

Comment: It does nearly everything but doesnt display the level of entry, and when your second one say the level of entry is undefined everytime i tried. @webeno

Comment: FORGET the first one, the 2nd one should only show `undefined` if you did something wrong, but I'm not magician, won't see your computer... if you're unable to implement a simple jsfiddle, then you'll have to practice a little more, play with it a little more, read my answer again and again, try to understand it, and hopefully one day you'll get it... sorry, can't help you more...

Comment: @webeno So the second jsfiddle worked for you? didplayed it and didnt show undefined?

Comment: Nah every time i tried the second jsfddle you made (the one that's meant to display it) always came up with "Level of Entry: undefined" no matter which level i choose @webeno

Comment: Not meant to be a Nah^

Comment: which one is "the 2nd one" for you?... by the way, if you're trying it in jsfiddle (on that very link), then it should work, if you're copying it from there and putting it in your testing environment, then it can fail for a number of reasons no one on this earth can tell unless you shared the full code or your monitor with them... so question 1: which link (exactly!) are you using when you say "2nd"? question 2: what's the OS / browser you're testing this in? question 3: is it failing in jsfiddle or on your test environment (are you copying)?

Comment: @webeno First one sorry**

Comment: @webeno It does in both, in jsfiddle and in where i copied (http://jsfiddle.net/Qd8sk/1/)

Comment: sorry, can't help you, i tried it on both, have no "undefined" message, i have no idea what your problem may be...

Comment: i managed to reproduce your undefined error but only on Firefox; for some reason it doesn't understand `document.formname.inputname.value` correctly for radio buttons... I updated the fiddle with a workaround to that; it works on both, chrome and firefox: [http://jsfiddle.net/Qd8sk/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/Qd8sk/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function confirm () {
     var alerttxt = "Are you sure you want to choose",
         value = document.ExamEntry.name.value;

     alerttxt += value;

     alert(alerttxt);
}
```

The value variable holds the value the user chose in the radio button, you just want to append that to a message you make up and display that whole txt in an alert

Comment: What about **the level can be confirmed or rejected.** ?

Comment: why would you use different code than what the OP already provided?

Comment: @MikeGrabowski Hi Thanks, How would i put this into the program and call it up, ideally i need it to come up when the submit is clicked